# "UPDATE cms_content WHERE title='homepage" SET value = ?"

Tags: php, mysqli

Lisa again... As said earlier, I'm making a system, and I want to load content from a database, in my AdminCP I want users to be able to edit the content, so this is what I'm doing in changecontent.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['change_content'])) {
  $name = $_POST['content'];
  $errorscontent = $users->changeContent($text);
}
```

And the other file:

```
    public function changeContent($text) {
    $errorscontent = array();
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE cms_content WHERE title='homepage' SET text = ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $text);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $errorsslide[] = "<div class='alert alert-success'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</button><strong>Success!</strong> Homepage content Changed successfully!</div>";
    return $errorscontent;
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Lisa

Comment: You need to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: Invalid SQL syntax and no error checking

Answer (score 2):

`SET` must come before `WHERE` in your query:

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE cms_content WHERE title='homepage' SET text = ? ");
```

should be:

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE cms_content SET text = ? WHERE title='homepage' ");
```

Comment: haha I posted the same but slower than you, just deleted it  .. :)

Comment: John must've asked for a shot of Espresso for his coffee this morning @AbhikChakraborty ;-) He's beaten me already this morning, but mine was just plain coffee, no Espresso.

Comment: yeah I guess so.. he was too quick this morning this happened 2nd time even before I finished typing he had an answer double in content than that I wrote :-)

Comment: Okay guys, nice that John had Espresso (I did) But it still doesn't work. When I run it, nothing happens ://

Comment: @JohnConde Like this? `  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE cms_functions  SET value = ? WHERE title='Slider' ");
  if ( false===$stmt ) {
     die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
  }
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
  $stmt->execute();
  if ( false===$stmt ) {
     die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
  }`